# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SparkSql at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

SparkSql.scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


object SparkSql
{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("SparkSql1").getOrCreate()

   //val data = spark.sparkContext.textFile(("C:\\Users\\blaskar\\Desktop\\Biswajit\\data\\sample.txt"))


    val data = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema","true").option("header","true").load("C:\\Users\\blaskar\\Desktop\\Biswajit\\data\\SampleCSVFile.csv")
    val columnsRenamed = Seq("S.no", "Eldonbase", "platnium","Macintyre","count1","count2","count3","Nunavut","Storage","count4")
    val original_data = data.toDF(columnsRenamed:_*).persist()
    original_data.show(10)

  }
}
```

build.sbt

```
name := "Spark-Sample1"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0" exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0" exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"))
```

VERSIONS OF SOFTWARE THE SYSTEM IS USING
spark: 2.1.0
scala: 2.11.8

I am using IntelliJ. The code is running fine but when I am submitting the job to my standalone cluster it is showing the below error:

SPARK-SUBMIT ERROR:

```
spark-submit --class "SparkSql" C:\Users\blaskar\Desktop\sbt_projects\Spark-Sample1
\out\artifacts\Spark_Sample1_jar\Spark-Sample1.jar
```

ERROR

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SparkSql
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:229)
    at
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:695)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: The current jar does not include the dependency try using sbt assembly that generate jar with dependency]

Comment: can you post the tree structure of your class. I guess you are not giving the correct path of your SparkSql class.

Comment: There's a space in `C:\Users\blaskar\Desktop\sbt_projects\Spark-Sample1 \out\artifacts\Spark_Sample1_jar\Spark-Sample1.jar` which makes it two arguments for `spark-submit` and possibly the error.

Comment: Use sbt-pack or sbt-assembly to package all the necessary jars for deployment

Comment: Hi @RameshMaharjan..    I have added the picture above . Kindly click the link.  I also found out that when I run the jar in intellij it shows                          Error: Unable to read or load main class SparkSql

Comment: the picture says that the main class is `Spark_Sql` and the path is also incorrect, so correct command is `spark-submit --class Spark_Sql C:\Users\blaskar\Desktop\sbt_projects\spark_final \out\artifacts\spark_final_jar\spark_final.jar`